# Ruby: connect to Couchbase

Tags: ruby, couchbase

I want to connect to Couchbase DB server trough [couchbase gem](https://github.com/couchbase/couchbase-ruby-client).

```
require 'couchbase'
c = Couchbase.connect('http://<server>:<port>/pools/default/buckets/auth')
```

I get an error:

```
*** Couchbase::Error::BucketNotFound Exception: bootstrap error, The bucket requested does not exist
```

The following code works with the ([couchbase python package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/couchbase)):

```
from couchbase.bucket import Bucket
c = Bucket('couchbase://<server>/auth')
```

How I can connect from ruby by using connection string `couchbase://<server>/auth`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need specify bucket if it is [custom](https://github.com/couchbase/couchbase-ruby-client/blob/master/lib/couchbase.rb#L52):

```
Couchbase.connect("http://<server>:8091/pools/default", :bucket => 'auth')
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I see on my machine.

```
# ruby --version
ruby 1.8.7 (2013-06-27 patchlevel 374) [x86_64-linux]

# gem --version
1.3.7

# gem list --local

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

connection_pool (2.2.0)
couchbase (1.3.14)
multi_json (1.12.1)
yaji (0.3.5)

# cat test.ruby
require 'couchbase'
c = Couchbase.connect('http://localhost:8091/pools/default/buckets/BUCKETNAME')
puts c.get('test123')


# cbc get test123 -U couchbase://localhost/BUCKETNAME 
test123              CAS=0x8f1269ea6014, Flags=0x0. Size=17
{"hello":"there"}

# ruby -rubygems test.ruby
[WARNING] MultiJson is using the default adapter (ok_json). We recommend loading a different JSON library to improve performance.
hellothere
```

This was on one of my Couchbase nodes.  I have bucket called BUCKETNAME and it contains a document with key "test123" and the content of the document is

```
{
  "hello": "there"
}
```

Comment: But when i connecting from python `Bucket('couchbase://<server>/auth')` - success, and when i connecting to the same server from ruby `Couchbase.connect('http://<server>:<port>/pools/default/buckets/auth')` i've got the error `Couchbase::Error::Auth: bootstrap error, Authentication failed. You may have provided an invalid username/password combination`. Both libraries used the same web admin port - 8091